# When I refresh the page, I get two responses

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an angular 6 application, there's a sidebar component

`sidebar.ts`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if (!Array.isArray(this.menu) || !this.menu.length) {
      const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
      this.item = data.response;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.item.menu.length; i++) {
        if (this.item.menu[i] && this.item.menu[i].section === 'left_menu') {
          if (this.menu.indexOf(this.item.menu[i].id) === -1) {
            this.menu.push(this.item.menu[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(data.response); // this is getting called twice
    }
  }
```

`sidebar.html`

```
<ul class="sidenav">
    <span *ngFor="let item of menu">
        <li id="{{item.id}}">
            <a href="{{item.menu_url}}">
                <i class="{{item.class_name}}"></i>
                <span>{{item.title}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </span>
    <li>
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="goTo(logout)">
            <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span>Log Out</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`app.html`

```
<app-left-sidebar *ngIf="showMenu"></app-left-sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and app.ts

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    const login = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'));
    if (login !== undefined && login === true) {

      if (location.pathname === '/login') {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
        this.showMenu = false;
      } else {
        this.showMenu = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (location.pathname === '/login') {
        this.showMenu = false;
      } else {
        this.showMenu = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

I have two problems

- The log out button isn't displayed in the sidebar, but rather on the login page and I have no clue why
- If I login, the sidebar is displayed correctly but I refresh, I receive duplicate response and as you can see I tried my best to filter them out, it's not working, I still see duplicate items in the sidebar when I refresh, could it be that it's getting called once on `app.ts` and once on `sidebar.ts`?

console.log shows that both requests are coming from the sidebar, same line is getting called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If console.log is being called twice, that means ngOnInit is being called twicw, that can only happen if when component id initialised twice or may be component is being called from 2 different places, or please check if you are doing same operation in ngOnChanges

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share the code through stackblitz. You can set this.menu = []; before the forloop in ngOnInit().

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (!Array.isArray(this.menu) || !this.menu.length) {
      const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
      this.item = data.response;
      this.menu = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.item.menu.length; i++) {
        if (this.item.menu[i] && this.item.menu[i].section === 'left_menu') {
          if (this.menu.indexOf(this.item.menu[i].id) === -1) {
            this.menu.push(this.item.menu[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(data.response); // this is getting called twice
    }
  }
```